# rlim_t errors with login_cap.h in Debian

Tags: c, linux, debian, header-files, freebsd

I'm trying to compile the `bsdmainutils` package in Debian that uses the `/usr/include/login_cap.h` header (from `libutil-freebsd-dev`), and I'm getting a bunch of errors like this:

```
/usr/include/login_cap.h:114:62: error: unknown type name ‘rlim_t’;
did you mean ‘__rlim_t’?
rlim_t login_getcapsize(login_cap_t *, const char *, rlim_t, rlim_t);
```

I'm using Debian testing. Is this a bug in `login_cap.h`? I see `rlim_t` defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/resource.h` - can I just include that file within login_cap.h? If so, do I have to include the arch-dependent path or does GCC do something special and let me do like `#include <sys/bits/resource.h>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to partially answer my question, this issue is resolved by adding `#include <sys/resource.h>` to `login_cap.h`. So, maybe either `login_cap.h` needs to come like this or `bsdmainutils` needs to include `sys/resource.h`.

I made a Debian bug report for this issue here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882728 but I don't know if my solution is correct.